# Not getting correct result with DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to fetch the machines that have been stuck in creating state for longer than 4 hours. I tried to run this query in CosmosDB and it works as expected, however in .Net function app, it returns 0 results. Can someone help with what might be the issue here:

```
var comparableDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4);
var query = this._repo.GetItemsQuery(poolId)
     .Where(vm =>
     vm.PoolId.Equals(poolId) &&
     vm.LabId.Equals(labId) &&
     (vm.State == ResourceState.Creating && vm.CreatedTime < comparableDate)
     );
```

Some of the rows that should be retrieved by the query are:

```
[
  {
    "SubscriptionId": <subscriptionId>,
    "ResourceGroupName": "tb-med-rg-ppe-0-bl-2",
    "Region": "eastus",
    "LabName": <LabName>,
    "VmName": <VMName>,
    "PoolId": <PoolId>,
    "LabId": <LabId>,
    "State": "Creating",
    "CreatedTime": "2022-12-09T11:18:32.8312471Z",
    "LabCreatedTime": null,
    "PrivateIPAddress": null,
    "LeaseId": <leaseId>,
    "LeasedUntil": "2022-12-09T15:18:32.8323785Z",
    "id": <id>
  },
  {
    "SubscriptionId": <subscriptionId>,
    "ResourceGroupName": "tb-med-rg-ppe-0-bl-2",
    "Region": "eastus",
    "LabName": <LabName>,
    "VmName": <VMName>,
    "PoolId": <PoolId>,
    "LabId": <LabId>,
    "State": "Creating",
    "CreatedTime": "2022-12-09T13:45:16.996413Z",
    "LabCreatedTime": null,
    "PrivateIPAddress": null,
    "LeaseId": <leaseId>,
    "LeasedUntil": "2022-12-09T17:45:16.9973301Z",
    "id": <id>
  },
  {
    "SubscriptionId": <subscriptionId>,
    "ResourceGroupName": "tb-med-rg-ppe-0-bl-2",
    "Region": "eastus",
    "LabName": <LabName>,
    "VmName": <VMName>,
    "PoolId": <PoolId>,
    "LabId": <LabId>,
    "State": "Creating",
    "CreatedTime": "2022-12-09T17:12:10.3620983Z",
    "LabCreatedTime": null,
    "PrivateIPAddress": null,
    "LeaseId": <leaseId>,
    "LeasedUntil": "2022-12-09T21:12:10.3653741Z",
    "id": <id>
  }
]
```

And the function `GetItemsQuery` is defined as:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetItemsQuery(string partitionKey = "")
{
       var container = this.containerFactory.GetContainer(this.ContainerProperties.Id);
       QueryRequestOptions options = new QueryRequestOptions
            {
                PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey),
            };

            return container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, null, options);

        }
```

Comment: We don't know what's the state of your database. Maybe provide test rows that you have tried to retrieve?

Comment: Can add more information? Like the method `GetItemsQuery` and the type of `vm`.

Comment: Added the information above @vernou

Comment: It is also possible that the utc time is calculated incorrectly.

Log "comparableDate" and "CreatedTime" to check if the desired utc is being calculated.

Comment: I did check that, they seem to be correct. @Dang-gunRoleeyas

Comment: I removed the linq-to-sql tag, because it's definitely not that. Please use a tag for the ORM + version you're using.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow “02-01-2023 05:05:17” with CreatedTime "2022-12-09T13:45:16.996413Z" but format of both the dates is different and the query won’t return any record. @RichaDua

Answer (score -1):

In C# .net

As per your code, you have used C# code DateTime.UtcNow to get UTC datetime.

**DateTime.UtcNow** returns value as “02-01-2023 05:05:17”. Please refer below screenshot.
[image]

The value you want to compare **CreatedTime** which value is "2022-12-09T13:45:16.996413Z".

Now if we compare, DateTime.UtcNow to CreatedTime but format of both the dates is different and the query won’t return any record.

Please refer below screenshot

[image]

Query which returned the result.

[image]

As per above analysis, if we are comparing fields then the format of fields must be same.

The data stored for “CreatedTime” field in “yyyy-MM-dd” format and the code var comparableDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4); which will return date in “MM-dd-yyyy” format.

As both the date formats are not same then queries won’t return any record.

```
SELECT  *  FROM c where c.PoolId = 'PoolId1' 
and c.LabId ='LabId1'and c.State = 'Creating'
and c.CreatedTime <  '02-01-2023'
```

[image]

But when we change the date format to “MM-dd-yyyy” then the query will return the records.

```
SELECT c.Region, c.CreatedTime, c.State, c.LabId FROM c 
where c.PoolId ='PoolId1' and c.LabId = 'LabId1'
and c.State = 'Creating'and c.CreatedTime < '2023-01-02'
```

[image]

Using `Convert.ToDateTime` you can convert "CreatedTime" to dd-MM-YYYY format which will be in same format as `DateTime.UtcNow;`.
[image][image]

Comment: First of all, `DateTime.UtcNow` returns a `DateTime` object and not a `string`. How this `DateTime` object is displayed is a totally different matter. You may still be right though (eventhough your reasoning is wrong), because if the `CreatedTime` is indeed a string, the issue may be with an implicit conversion. But if that's the case, the more reasonable approach would be to convert the `comparableDate` to the same string format as the stored date with `comparableDate.ToString("s")` ...

Comment: Here requirement is to compare to date values. If we store dates in string format, then on strings values less than (<) or greater than (>) operations won’t be possible.

Comment: If `CreatedTime` is really a `DateTime` your answer doesn't make any sense, because as already said: A `DateTime` is agnostic of any display format ...